# Understanding Div classes in Foundation 4

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am just beginning with Foundation 4 (coming from Bootstrap). There are a few concepts which I really cannot grasp, and there is no sign of explanation in their docs:

I have the following:

```
<div class="small-2 large-4 columns" style="background-color:lightgrey">. . .</div>
<div class="small-2 large-4 columns" style="background-color:lightgrey">. . .</div>
<div class="small-2 large-4 columns" style="background-color:lightgrey">. . .</div>
```

I really cannot understand what does small-2 and large-4 *combined* mean. In bootstrap there was just span* so I am guessing `small-*` is the same, but what about `large-*`? What does the large stand for? It also seems to me that I can omit one of the two, and have just `large-*` or `small-*`.

Also, what about the `columns` class? Why do I even need that if the "span" is already defined by the other classes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using '*small*' and '*large*' you can define a column structure for small size screens and one for large size screens. So in your set up above when viewing in a large screen you would see four columns, and when in small you would see two columns.

e.g.

Large

```
|  1 |  2 |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10 |  11 |  12 |

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     |                       |                       |
|   div1              |      div2             |      div3             |    
|                     |                       |                       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Small

```
|  1 |  2 |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10 |  11 |  12 |

-----------------------------------
|         |           |           |
|  div1   |   div2    |   div3    |    
|         |           |           |
-----------------------------------
```

If you only use '*large-#*' and omit a '*small-#*' value, when viewing in on a small screen it defaults to 12 columns, essentially the same as writing *small-12 large-4*.

If you use only a '*small-#*' and omit a '*large-#*' value when viewing on all screen sizes it will use the '*small-#*' value.

The '*column*' class defines the div as a column. If you do not define and '*small-#*' or '*large-#*' it will set the div to 100% width (i.e. 12 columns).

Foundation also uses '*row*'.

If you wrap a set of '*column*' divs in a '*row*' div all the '*column*' divs will attempt to sit on the same row, if the total number of columns defined in a row is above 12 they will wrap. If the total number of columns is less than 12 then the columns will not wrap.

2 rows

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns" style="background-color:lightgrey">...</div>
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns" style="background-color:lightgrey">...</div>
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns end" style="background-color:lightgrey">...</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns" style="background-color:lightgrey">...</div>
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns end" style="background-color:lightgrey">...</div>
</div>
```

Large

```
|  1 |  2 |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10 |  11 |  12 |

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     |                       |                       |
|   div1              |      div2             |      div3             |  (row 1)
|                     |                       |                       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------
|                     |                       |
|   div1              |      div2             |   (row 2)
|                     |                       |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Small

```
|  1 |  2 |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10 |  11 |  12 |

-----------------------------------
|         |           |           |
|  div1   |   div2    |   div3    |    (row 1)
|         |           |           |
-----------------------------------

-----------------------
|         |           |
|  div1   |   div2    |    (row 2)
|         |           |
-----------------------
```

now with 1 row

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns" style="background-color:lightgrey">. . .</div>
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns" style="background-color:lightgrey">. . .</div>
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns" style="background-color:lightgrey">. . .</div>
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns" style="background-color:lightgrey">. . .</div>
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns end" style="background-color:lightgrey">. . .</div>   
</div>
```

Large - 1-row columns greater than 12 so they wrap

```
|  1 |  2 |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10 |  11 |  12 |

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     |                       |                       |
|   div1              |      div2             |      div3             |    
|                     |                       |                       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     |                       |
|   div4              |      div5             |
|                     |                       |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Small - 1-row columns are less than 12, no wrapping

```
|  1 |  2 |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10 |  11 |  12 |

-----------------------------------------------------------
|         |           |           |           |           |
|  div1   |   div2    |   div3    |   div4    |   div5    |     
|         |           |           |           |           |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Hope this helps.

**Note:** When not using exactly 12 column as per the above layouts you need to add the class '*end*' to the last column in the row to make it float left as the last column floats right by default.

e.g.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns" style="background-color:lightgrey">...</div>
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns" style="background-color:lightgrey">...</div>
</div>
```

Without the end class would look like this:

Large

```
|  1 |  2 |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10 |  11 |  12 |


-----------------------                        ------------------------
|                     |                        |                      |
|   div1              |                        |      div2            | 
|                     |                        |                      |
-----------------------                        ------------------------
```

Small

```
|  1 |  2 |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10 |  11 |  12 |


-----------                                                ------------
|         |                                                |          |
|  div1   |                                                |  div2    |
|         |                                                |          |
-----------                                                ------------
```

Comment: How come when I do the what you just did and when adding 7 large-4 inside one row, the seventh one (in the 3rd row) is floated to the right? For some reason this css selector applied to it

    [class*="column"] + [class*="column"]:last-child {
        float: right;
    }

Comment: it is just the way Foundation works, the last column is always floated right. You can float it left by adding 'end' to the class of your final column.