# ZURB Foundation: Should I create row for every "row"?

Tags: zurb-foundation

So, Can I create one `<div class="row">` and push there columns? The total length of columns will be larger 12 units. Is it bad style and I should create row for every row?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the behaviour you want. If you have more than 12 columns in a row they will wrap on to the next line as it were

more than 12 columns in one row will wrap

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">. . .</div>
 <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">. . .</div>
 <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">. . .</div>
 <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">. . .</div>
 <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">. . .</div>   
</div>

|  1 |  2 |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10 |  11 |  12 |

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     |                       |                       |
|   div1              |      div2             |      div3             |    
|                     |                       |                       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     |                       |
|   div4              |      div5             |
|                     |                       |
-----------------------------------------------
```

equivalent in 2 rows

```
    <div class="row">
     <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">...</div>
     <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">...</div>
     <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">...</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">...</div>
     <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">...</div>
     <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">...</div>
   </div>

|  1 |  2 |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10 |  11 |  12 |

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     |                       |                       |
|   div1              |      div2             |      div3             |  (row 1)
|                     |                       |                       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------
|                     |                       |
|   div1              |      div2             |   (row 2)
|                     |                       |
-----------------------------------------------
```

There is a bit more detail here [Understanding Div classes in Foundation 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394820/understanding-div-classes-in-foundation-4/17443887#17443887)